# While Loop v. For Loop while removing objects form array

Tags: loops

I have a question about using a `for` loop versus using a `while` loop.

When using a `for` loop, when I test for `i < [array count]`, is it the count at first execution, or will it decrement as I remove objects and iterate through the loop?

I believe it to be the latter, as I was unable to reach all items...

```
for(int i=0; i < [array count] ++i) {
    //do some operations
    [array removeObjectAtIndex:i];
}
```

I then switched my loop to a while loop. It appears to iterate correctly but I was under the assumption that I should be able to accomplish the same task with either.

```
while([array count] > 0) {
    //do some operations
    [array removeObjectAtIndex:[array count] - 1];
}
```

I think I'm doing something wrong here, can anyone share their ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you remove using a for loop you have to maintain the index location because the array count changes after each remove:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++) {
    // remove object at index i
    // decrement i here cause the i++ will set it back
}
```

Here's what happens if you don't decrement `i` after each remove:  array has {1, 2, 3}.

- First iteration for array has a count of 3 and i = 0
- Element 1 (index 0) is removed and now count is 2, but i moves to 1
- array is now {2, 3} and i is 1 so we would remove Element 3 and i move to 2
- Loop exits leaving {2}

With the `while` loop remove you would always want to remove the same index (either the first element or the last element ([array count] - 1))

```
while ([array count] > 0) {
    // Remove element at index 0, or remove the last element
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, my issue was not decrementing i

Answer (score 0):

After removing that index location, the elements beyond it will all decrease their index number by one. So if you start from zero in a for loop and increment each time, you will delete every other element

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for an opinion not an answer.
I would prefer for-loop over while-loop because if not used properly, while-loop can go into an infinite loop. Not so easy in case of for-loop. In a for loop, the value is initialized, condition is checked, statements are executed and then value is incremented/decremented before checking condition again.